# Google line charts drawing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, linechart

The weights that have been calculated in program needs to be displayed in a graph. I have added into the code an example taken from here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#creating-material-line-charts
Obviously the variable data needs to be replaced by weight, so the existing data (line 17 to 31) can be discarded. The latest version of the code is attached

```
<html>
<head>
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['line'] });  // load the visualisation API and corechart package
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);               // set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded

// Callback that creates and populates a data table, instantiates the chart, passes in the data and draws it.
function drawChart() {
  // Create the data table for the symbol in question.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'k');
  data.addColumn('number', 'lambda');

  data.addRows([
    [-0.050, 0.00952],
    [-0.040, 0.00952],
    [-0.030, 0.01904],
    [-0.025, 0.03809],
    [-0.020, 0.02857],
    [-0.015, 0.04761],
    [-0.010, 0.02857],
    [-0.005, 0.18095],
    [0.000, 0.21904],
    [0.005, 0.16190],
    [0.010, 0.12380],
    [0.015, 0.05714],
    [0.020, 0.03809],
    [0.030, 0.02857],
    [0.080, 0.00952]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('#chart_weights'));
  chart.draw(data, { height: 288, width: 550, lineWidth: 1 });
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td>k: </td><td><input id="k" type="number" value="2.2" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>lambda: </td><td><input id="lambda" type="number" value="7.6" min="0" max="10" step="0.1" /></td></tr>
</table>

<p id="message"> </p>

<script type="text/javascript">
UpdateValues();

document.getElementById("k").addEventListener("click", function() {
  UpdateValues();
});

document.getElementById("lambda").addEventListener("click", function() {
  UpdateValues();
});

function UpdateValues() {
  var weight = [];
  var k = document.getElementById("k").value;
  var lambda = document.getElementById("lambda").value;
  for (var x = 0.1; x < 20; x++) {
    weight.push([x, k * Math.pow(x/lambda, k-1) * Math.exp(-Math.pow(x/lambda, k)) / lambda]);
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = weight;
  }
}
</script>
<div id="chart_weights"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why these graphs are not beiNg displayed..
THanks in advance to helping hands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, check [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/savchenko/tq6sqxdw/4/)

So, The main problem was that `Container is not defined`.

In your code you write `document.getElementById('#chart_weights')` but you should write `document.getElementById('chart_weights')` without `#`.

Comment: alright, I did what you said, but my graph is same on every value it's not changing..

Comment: @NATS If you want to update chart dynamically you should put `drawChart()` into `UpdateValues()`

Comment: I tried to put the <code>drawChart()</code> into <code>UpdateValues()</code> but that's still not working,
I also tried to invoke <code>drawChart()</code> but still not able to update chart dynamically

Comment: @NATS you expect something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/savchenko/tq6sqxdw/3/)? Also, do you check [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/)? It can be useful for you

Comment: What I want is whenever I change the value of lambda/k the graph should be changed automatically i.e. without click anywhere.

Comment: @NATS you chould use event `change`. Updated my [example](https://jsfiddle.net/savchenko/tq6sqxdw/4/)

Comment: yes, exactly the same thing but I want this to be done in my code..
what would I need to do.

Comment: @NATS This code is same as yours but little bit optimized. Main changes are: 1) changed `document.getElementById('#chart_weights')` to `document.getElementById('chart_weights')` 2) changed `.addEventListener("click"` to `.addEventListener("change"` 3) updated `google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(UpdateValues);` 4) `data.addRows(weight);`

Comment: alright, the code is working fine now, however the graph is not plotting k nor lambda values ? how to plot them ?

Comment: Read Google chart documentation and add columns

Comment: chart.draw(data, { height: 288, width: 550, lineWidth: 1 })
lineWidth here is not working, what would be the reason ?
By google I tried to make another variable "options" and changed the lineWidth finally  passed that as argument in chart.draw but that doesn't worked either

Comment: @NATS it should be placed in options. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/lines#changing-the-thickness

Comment: If my answers helps you could you vote for accept it?

Comment: sure, and thankYou so much,
one last thiNg is, it is still not working in {options} :(

Comment: Could you provide some example? If it will be on pastebin it will be perfect

Comment: [Material Line Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#creating-material-line-charts) doesn't support all of options and `lineWidth` in this list. Sorry. If you change your chart to default Line Chart - everything works well. You can read documentation for explanation.